# UserData or Bootstrapping in AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, aws-serverless

I have an ECS cluster - EC2-based built using Terraform. The Autoscaling group for this cluster has been configured that is having User-Data. Now, I want to migrate this ECS cluster from EC2 to Fargate. How I can migrate/mention user-data when I'm defining Autoscaling configuration for Fargate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How I can migrate/mention user-data

You don't. User data is only for EC2 instances, and in Fargate you have no control over them. You have to  abandon your user-data, as it has no use in you Fargate.

Comment: Yeah I think, that's the only option.